# Why do lentils turn gray in the fridge?

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation, refrigerator, lentils

After cooking brown lentils, they come out in their usual light brown color. But after one day of refrigeration, they turn this color of gray. This has happened every time I save leftover lentils. Why is that? Are they safe to eat?

[image: gray lentils]

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [this question about lentils](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/58493/is-it-normal-for-the-colour-of-the-cooked-lentils-to-change-overnight-even-when) where the answer suggests the problem is due to oxidation. If you’ve followed the guidelines mentioned in [this other question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat) they’re probably safe to eat

Comment: I would say it's a duplicate. Green lentils may turn a different green, brown lentils turn grey, and so on - the reason is the same, and we don't need a separate question for each kind of lentil.